# How to use the values of page for the meta tag of other in php ?

Tags: php, facebook-opengraph

I have two pages which content is being fed dynamically, the first one index.php includes the other page person.php when I click on the link:

**index.php :**

```
<?php include("db1.php");
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('blog/wp-blog-header.php');
$pages=array(
                 "person"=>"person.php"


                 ); 

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<meta property="og:title" content=""/>

    <meta property="og:url" content=""/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content=""/>
    <meta property="og:description" content=""/>
</head>

<body>
<?
    $sql="select id, name,title,image from persons  where cat =10 ";
    $rs=mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
    if(list($id,$name,$title,$image)=mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
        ?>
<a href="?page=person&p=<? echo $id;?>" id="<? echo $id;?>" class="details">
<?
    }
    ?>
<div class="twelve columns" id="persons">

        <?
if($_GET["page"]=="")
                    $p="persons1";
                else
                    $p=$_GET["page"];

                if($pages[$p]!="")
                    include($pages[$p]);
                else
                    echo "page not found ";
                    ?>
                  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Page 2 : person.php:**

```
<? include("db1.php");?>
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('blog/wp-blog-header.php');
?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="twelve columns">
        <div class="eight columns">

    <?
    if(isset($_GET['p'])){
$id=str_replace('-',' ',(string)$_GET['p']);
$name1="";
    $sql="select id, name,title,details,image,cat from persons  where name ='".$id."' order by name asc";
    $rs=mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
    if(list($id,$name,$title,$details,$image,$cat)=mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
        $a=$name;
  ?>
    <h3><? echo $name;?></h3>
    <h5><? echo $title;?></h5>
    <p align="justify">
        <img alt="<? echo $name;?>" src="images/persons/<? echo $image?>" title="<? echo $name;?>" style="float:right; margin-left:15px;" />
        <? echo $details;?>
    </p>
    <?
    }
    }
?>
```

How to use the values of person.php page in the meta tags of index.php when the page is included ?

Comment: Where's the data in `person.php` that you want to use? On the face of it this should be pretty simple because `person.php` does not use any of the data it has inherited from `index.php` so it can be run at the top of the script and the result caught in the output buffer, to just be `echo`ed later on. Also, let me introduce you to an old enemy of mine called [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: I want to use ($name,$title,$details,$image) the result of MySQL select in person.php in the meta tag of index .php, the problem is person should be included after the head tag because of my page structure

Comment: OK, well I don't want to just *give* you the answer until you've tried it yourself or you won't learn anything, but here's all the info you should need to accomplish this: You'll need to move the logic that `include`s the file to the top of `index.php`, above the `<!DOCTYPE>`. You'll need to use [output buffering](http://php.net/ob-start) to catch the output of `person.php` so that it can be output in the correct place. Once the file has been included, the variables it creates will be available in index.php. I'll happily help if you have any questions on this, but go have a play around first.

Comment: including the person before <!DOCTYPE > will put the information in the wrong place the data of person which includes also html should be in the place where I am including it !!

Comment: thank you I could get the values ! and it appears in the meta tag I I viewed the source of page but the https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug says :

Object Missing a Required Value: Object at URL 'http://www.palestinianz.com/' of type 'website' is invalid because a required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was not provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the variables you want to use using the php global keyword to define your variables in both of your files. See here for details: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

However, using generic names like you have ($name,$title,$details,$image) is bound to cause conflicts, especially in a Wordpress environment. Your best bet is to choose a unique variable name, declare it as an array, and set each of these items as elements:

```
 global $amer_enaya_fb_metadata;
 $amer_enaya_fb_metadata = array( 'name' => $name, ... );
```